# generic type usage as value in an abstract class<T, K extends keyof T>

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to move some logic to an abstract class.
Consider the abstract generic class with following constraints:

```
abstract class AbstractVersion<
    TModel extends object,
    TProperty extends keyof TModel,
    TValue = TModel[TProperty]> {

    private _version: TValue;
    public get version(): TValue {
        return this._version;
    }
}
```

So this can be extended by example

```
class MyVersionedModel extends AbstractVersion<MyModel, 'MyNumericId'>
```

So far, so good. But now I want to use my TProperty-type as a value, could something like this be possible?

```
abstract class AbstractVersion<
    TModel extends object,
    TProperty extends keyof TModel,
    TValue = TModel[TProperty]> {

    private _version: TValue;
    public get version(): TValue {
        return this._version;
    }

    set(model: TModel): void {
        this._version = model[TProperty];
    }

    apply(fx: (property: string, value: TValue) => boolean): boolean {
        return fx(TProperty.toString(), this.version);
    }
}
```

So obviously I'm getting a syntax error `'TProperty' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`
on `model[TProperty]` and `TProperty.toString()`, but is there a way to access TProperty as a value?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, because generics are not available at runtime. You need to pass the property name at runtime somehow (maybe in the constructor?)

Comment: I second that. You could try to use the name of the constructor function of your type but that is horribly unreliable as that changes with minification. I suggest either passing the name through the constructor or an abstract method that returns the name (or a field that holds it, but the method has the advantage that it can be abstract and implementation would be enforced).

Comment: So with a "duplicate" constructor argument ``constructor(private property: TProperty)`` would be the best approach?
Implementation
```class MyVersionedModel extends AbstractVersion<MyModel, 'OtherIdentifier'> {
    constructor() {
        super('OtherIdentifier');
    }
}```

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible, because all your Typings aren't available during runtime. Remember that Typescript gets compiled down to JavaScript and JavaScript doesn't know about types.

You would need to specify somewhere the valid key, as suggested in the comments as a constructor argument would be the best place, I think.